# Added Custom Font to C# WPF label. Won't Display When Application Is Running

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, fonts

I'm attempting to add a custom font to my C# WPF application using Visual Studio 2019.  This is for .Net Framework.

I imported a custom ttf to my Resources.resx.  In the visual layout xaml editor I was able to select this custom font ("jura") and see it displayed in a label control.    However, as soon as I run the application the label control reverts to another font even though the "FontFamily" property still reads as "jura" when I look in the debugger.

Here is the label code in the XAML editor:

```
<Label x:Name="_lbltest" Content="Jura PAGE 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" Background="#00000000"  Foreground="White"  FontSize="16" Canvas.Left="180" Canvas.Top="10" FontFamily="/cupruma;component/#Jura" />
```

How the font looks in the xaml editor.  This is the correct font:

[image: How the font looks in the XAML editor]

When I run the application this is how the font looks. It's wrong and looks like Segoe UI:

[image]

How can I fix it so that the label keeps the custom font when the application is running?

Thanks for any help!

...John

Answer (score 1):

For adding custom fonts, you could try to follow the steps below.

Add fonts to the project and make sure the fonts are resources：

[image]

```
  <Resource Include="JuraLight.ttf" />
```

[image]

When the resource is in Subdirectory：

```
<Resource Include="Fonts\JuraLight.ttf" />
```

[image]

MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="_lbltest" Content="Jura PAGE 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" Background="DarkBlue"  Foreground="White"  FontSize="16" FontFamily="./#Jura" />
        <Label x:Name="_lbltest3" Content="Jura PAGE 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" Background="DarkBlue"  Foreground="White"  FontSize="16" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Result:
[image]

See the [MSDN article on fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/packaging-fonts-with-applications?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still not able to get this working. I added the jura-light.ttf as a resource. They are there, because they show up at build time in XAML. But not when I run it.   I did try to add  <Resource Include="JuraLight.ttf" />, but I'm not sure where to put that in the project.    I tried a few places, and it warned me it wasn't compatible with WPF.

Comment: I was able to get it working by placing this in my App.xml file:     <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="lblDesign" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="jura-light.ttf #jura"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>         I included the font as a resource inside the application.

Comment: Hi,@John Alway. Where did you add the font file? What is your project structure? You can right-click the project to Unload Project. Then right-click the project and select Edit Project File to see what the path of your font file is. Find something similar to `<Resource Include="Fonts\JuraLight.ttf" />`

Comment: Hello @Hui Liu -MFST -- I was able to get it working a couple of days ago.  I provided my own answer on this page.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi,@John Alway.I am glad that your problem has been solved, and you could accept your solution as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I solved the issue using Visual Studio 2019:

1> I placed my custom font, jura-light.ttf, in the Resources folder in the Windows explorer.  I had early on in the project created and named the "Resources" folder where the project.sln file is.

2> In Visual Studio in the Solution Explorer I double clicked Resources.resx. This brings up the "Resources.resx" tab in the window.  I clicked on the tab and selected "Add Resource". This brings up a window where I can navigate.  I navigated to jura-light.ttf and added it.  The resource is now embedded.

3> Next I click on the "Resources" folder within Visual Studio.  Here I see the name of the file, which I can also get from the Windows folder.  I remember the name for the next step.

4>  In the App.xaml folder I added the following code.  "jura-light.ttf" is the custom font file name, and #jura is the font name. I stumbled on the name "jura" when I selected the font in the properties window for the label control.  It was the first entry.  That name has to be right to work. :

```
<Application.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="lblDesign" TargetType="Label">
       <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="jura-light.ttf #jura"/>
   </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

5> I used the code in a label where one of my xaml files is.  Here is the code:

```
<Label x:Name="_lbltest" Content="Jura PAGE 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"  FontSize="16" Style="{StaticResource lblDesign}" />
```

And that worked for me.